# Query data from Dataset designer using LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, datagridview, dataset, linq-to-objects

I want to filter data from `dataset` using `LINQ` and display the result to a `datagridview1`, which is bound to `datatable` in `dataset` designer.  However, when I type in the `textbox`, all the data in `datagridview` is gone.

This below code is the `LINQ` query that I use.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles MyBase.Load

    MethodGlobal.NewMysqlConnection()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM caricust"
    connection.Open()
    sCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, MethodGlobal.mySqlCon)
    sAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
    sBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
    sDs = New DataSet()
    sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "caricust")
    sTable = sDs.Tables("caricust")
    MethodGlobal.mySqlCon.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("caricust")
    DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim a As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim cari As DataTable = DataSet1.Tables("caricust")

    Dim query = _
    From caricust In cari.AsEnumerable() _
      Where caricust.Field(Of String)("nmlng").Contains(a) _
      Select caricust

    Dim view As DataView = query.AsDataView()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view
End Sub
```

What is wrong in my script?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't show the declaration for DataSet1. Where is it defined? Where is it populated?
2. You are assuming that `a` has a value. The `TextChanged` event fires every time text in the textbox changes. That includes when it goes to a zero length string.
3. You **need** error handling.

What errors are you getting when you either compile or run the code?

Comment: This is not an answer but a number of comments.

Comment: The OP asked "What is wrong in my script?" How is a list of errors not an answer?

Comment: OK, the question is not crystal clear, but I think it's about this: "However, when I type in the textbox, all the data in datagridview is gone".